# How to get iPhone model name in Titanium?

Tags: iphone, titanium

I want to know what kind of iPhone is running my app, so I use Titanium.Platform.model to get it.

As API documentation, Appcelerator said that Ti.Platform.model will return the model name of current device. But when I try on real iPhone (both 2G, 3G or 4), I see the returned model name is 'iPhone'. But my expected result is 'iPhone 2G' or 'iPhone 4'.

Is the API document wrong? Do we have other solution to determine if current device is iPhone 2G or not?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like you will ever get 2G back, but you should be getting iPhone 4. take a look at the [source code here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/c8915563edd1a85df024fc5612865319ac00c491/iphone/Classes/PlatformModule.m)

Comment: Thanks for your link. But unluckily, I only want to know if this device is iPhone 2G or not. Because in my app, I have a bug only occurs in iPhone 2G. It's the problem.